# KeyError when using melt to restructure Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that currently looks as follows and has 2628 rows and 101 columns. I want to convert the `years` row which is associated with the numbers `0.08333 0.16666 0.249999` and so on, into a column:

```
years      Currency  0.08333333  0.16666666  0.24999999  0.33333332  \
2005-01-04      GBP    4.709456    4.633861    4.586271    4.567017   
2005-01-05      GBP    4.713099    4.649220    4.606802    4.588313   
2005-01-06      GBP    4.707237    4.646861    4.609294    4.593076
```

The code is as follows, where `combined_data` is the dataframe. I used `melt` to do this but get the Error `KeyError: 'years'` and don't know how to handle this:

```
from pandas.io.excel import read_excel
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = 'http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/Documents/yieldcurve/uknom05_mdaily.xls'

# check the sheet number, spot: 9/9, short end 7/9
spot_curve = read_excel(url, sheetname=8)
short_end_spot_curve = read_excel(url, sheetname=6)

# do some cleaning, keep NaN for now, as forward fill NaN is not recommended for yield curve
spot_curve.columns = spot_curve.loc['years:']
spot_curve.columns.name = 'years'
valid_index = spot_curve.index[4:]
spot_curve = spot_curve.loc[valid_index]
# remove all maturities within 5 years as those are duplicated in short-end file
col_mask = spot_curve.columns.values > 5
spot_curve = spot_curve.iloc[:, col_mask]


short_end_spot_curve.columns = short_end_spot_curve.loc['years:']
short_end_spot_curve.columns.name = 'years'
valid_index = short_end_spot_curve.index[4:]
short_end_spot_curve = short_end_spot_curve.loc[valid_index]

# merge these two, time index are identical
# ==============================================
combined_data = pd.concat([short_end_spot_curve, spot_curve], axis=1, join='outer')
# sort the maturity from short end to long end
combined_data.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)

def filter_func(group):
    return group.isnull().sum(axis=1) <= 50

combined_data = combined_data.groupby(level=0).filter(filter_func)

idx = 0
values = ['GBP'] * len(combined_data.index)
combined_data.insert(idx, 'Currency', values)
print combined_data

pd.melt(combined_data,id_vars=['years']) #ERROR!
```

**Edit**: Desired Results:

```
years                     Currency  
0.08333333   2005-01-04      GBP    4.709456    4.633861    4.586271    4.567017   
0.16666666   2005-01-05      GBP    4.713099    4.649220    4.606802    4.588313   
0.24999999   2005-01-06      GBP    4.707237    4.646861    4.609294    4.593076
```

Comment: @JohnE I've edited the question. Yes, it is "years row" and not column and I've added the desired results.

Comment: Cool, that's much clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may need to be tweaked based on how many rows you have relative to columns, but will give you the desired results (more or less):

```
        years Currency  0.08333333  0.16666666  0.24999999  0.33333332
0  2005-01-04      GBP    4.709456    4.633861    4.586271    4.567017
1  2005-01-05      GBP    4.713099    4.649220    4.606802    4.588313
2  2005-01-06      GBP    4.707237    4.646861    4.609294    4.593076

df['x'] = df.columns.values[-4:-1]
df = df.set_index('x',drop=True)
df.columns = ['years','Currency','v1','v2','v3','v4']

                 years Currency        v1        v2        v3        v4
x                                                                      
0.08333333  2005-01-04      GBP  4.709456  4.633861  4.586271  4.567017
0.16666666  2005-01-05      GBP  4.713099  4.649220  4.606802  4.588313
0.24999999  2005-01-06      GBP  4.707237  4.646861  4.609294  4.593076
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've realized I made a mistake in how I wanted my output structure but I've accepted your answer as it would do the job for the question I asked here.

Comment: @FixIncome If you want to un-check the answer and re-do the question, I don't mind at all.  Although generally you'll get a better response from writing a new question since edits to old questions often get ignored (just how SO works, I guess)

Comment: That's fine. I've rewritten the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942466/restructuring-dataframe) if you're interested in checking it out.