# Restructuring Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that currently looks as follows and has 262800 rows and 3 columns. My dataframe is currently as follows:

```
       Currency    Maturity     value
0           GBP  0.08333333  4.709456
1           GBP  0.08333333  4.713099
2           GBP  0.08333333  4.707237
3           GBP  0.08333333  4.705043
4           GBP  0.08333333  4.697150
5           GBP  0.08333333  4.710647
6           GBP  0.08333333  4.701150
7           GBP  0.08333333  4.694639
8           GBP  0.08333333  4.686111
9           GBP  0.08333333  4.714750
......
262770      GBP          25  2.432869
```

I want the dataframe to be of the form below. I've taken some steps towards this, which included using `melt` in the code below, but for some reason that got rid of my `Date` Column and resulted in the dataframe above. I am unsure how to get the Date Column back and obtain the Dataframe below:

```
   Maturity     Date            Currency  Yield_pct
0  0.08333333   2005-01-04      GBP       4.709456              
1  0.08333333   2005-01-05      GBP       4.713099               
2  0.08333333   2005-01-06      GBP       4.707237
....
9  25           2005-01-04      GBP       2.432869
```

My code is as follows:

```
from pandas.io.excel import read_excel
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = 'http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/Documents/yieldcurve/uknom05_mdaily.xls'

# check the sheet number, spot: 9/9, short end 7/9
spot_curve = read_excel(url, sheetname=8)
short_end_spot_curve = read_excel(url, sheetname=6)

# do some cleaning, keep NaN for now, as forward fill NaN is not recommended for yield curve
spot_curve.columns = spot_curve.loc['years:']
spot_curve.columns.name = 'Maturity'
valid_index = spot_curve.index[4:]
spot_curve = spot_curve.loc[valid_index]
# remove all maturities within 5 years as those are duplicated in short-end file
col_mask = spot_curve.columns.values > 5
spot_curve = spot_curve.iloc[:, col_mask]


short_end_spot_curve.columns = short_end_spot_curve.loc['years:']
short_end_spot_curve.columns.name = 'Maturity'
valid_index = short_end_spot_curve.index[4:]
short_end_spot_curve = short_end_spot_curve.loc[valid_index]

# merge these two, time index are identical
# ==============================================
combined_data = pd.concat([short_end_spot_curve, spot_curve], axis=1, join='outer')
# sort the maturity from short end to long end
combined_data.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)

def filter_func(group):
    return group.isnull().sum(axis=1) <= 50

combined_data = combined_data.groupby(level=0).filter(filter_func)

idx = 0
values = ['GBP'] * len(combined_data.index)
combined_data.insert(idx, 'Currency', values) 

#print combined_data.columns.values

#I had to do the melt 
combined_data = pd.melt(combined_data,id_vars=['Currency'])#Arbitrarily melted on 'Currency' as for some reason when I do print combined_data.columns.values I see that 'Currency' corresponds to 0.08333333, etc.
print combined_data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not add the currency identifier following the `melt`?

```
# Copy up to this stage
combined_data = combined_data.groupby(level=0).filter(filter_func)

# My code from here
combined_data.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
combined_data.rename(columns={'index': 'Date'}, inplace=True)

# This line assumes you want datetime, ignore if you don't
combined_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(combined_data['Date'])

result = pd.melt(combined_data, id_vars=['Date'])

result['Currency'] = 'GBP'
```

Output of `result.head()`

```
    Date    Maturity    value   Currency
0   2005-01-04  0.08333333  4.709456    GBP
1   2005-01-05  0.08333333  4.713099    GBP
2   2005-01-06  0.08333333  4.707237    GBP
3   2005-01-07  0.08333333  4.705043    GBP
4   2005-01-10  0.08333333  4.697150    GBP
```

Comment: That's great. Can I ask one further question. Is there a way to change the Column name `value` into `Yield_pct`?

Comment: Sure, I personally like to use dictionaries as it is easy to see what it was before: ``result.rename(columns={'value': 'Yield_pct'}, inplace=True)``

Answer (score 0):

Try stacking your results after first resetting your index to include the currency.

```
cd = combined_data.reset_index().set_index(['index', 'Currency'])
cd_new = cd.stack()
>>> cd_new
index       Currency  Maturity
2005-01-04  GBP       0.083333    4.709456
                      0.166667    4.633861
                      0.250000    4.586271
                      0.333333    4.567017
                      0.416667    4.559578
                      0.500000    4.553227
                      0.583333    4.543976
                      0.666667    4.530881
                      0.750000    4.514742
                      0.833333    4.497187
                      0.916667    4.479690
                      1.000000    4.463105
                      1.083333    4.447843
                      1.166667    4.434076
                      1.250000    4.421868
...
2015-05-29  GBP       18.0        2.453898
                      18.5        2.475052
                      19.0        2.494679
                      19.5        2.512787
                      20.0        2.529393
                      20.5        2.544519
                      21.0        2.558198
                      21.5        2.570467
                      22.0        2.581368
                      22.5        2.590947
                      23.0        2.599250
                      23.5        2.606327
                      24.0        2.612229
                      24.5        2.617008
                      25.0        2.620715
Length: 259457, dtype: float64

cd_new.xs('2015-05-29')
Currency  Maturity
GBP       0.333333    0.452339
          0.416667    0.441134
          0.500000    0.430168
          0.583333    0.419990
          0.666667    0.411208
          0.750000    0.404424
          0.833333    0.400017
          0.916667    0.398140
          1.000000    0.398806
          1.083333    0.401943
          1.166667    0.407427
          1.250000    0.415095
          1.333333    0.424762
          1.416667    0.436233
          1.500000    0.449322
...
GBP       18.0        2.453898
          18.5        2.475052
          19.0        2.494679
          19.5        2.512787
          20.0        2.529393
          20.5        2.544519
          21.0        2.558198
          21.5        2.570467
          22.0        2.581368
          22.5        2.590947
          23.0        2.599250
          23.5        2.606327
          24.0        2.612229
          24.5        2.617008
          25.0        2.620715
Length: 97, dtype: float64
```